# MacBook Pro 2016 does not turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a MacBook Pro 2016 with a touch bar, and without prior warning it is now refusing to turn on. Pressing the Touch ID button does nothing: no chime, no screen activity, no computer noise, no Caps Lock LED. Resetting the SMC has no effect.

Is there any kind of diagnosis I can perform before bringing it to the Apple Store? Is there some secret key combination that will make it tell me where it's failing? Can I somehow connect it to a second computer and use that to perform a diagnosis?

Guides freely available through Google don't say very much beyond these steps that I've already taken.

I guess my real question is:

> What will Apple itself do before starting to dissemble it? Can I do that myself?

Comment: I assume, of course, that the MBP is plugged into a power source and that you've tried more than one of the USB-C ports to do so? If so, I agree with the answer offered by Allan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you press the power button and nothing happens, there's no special or secret combination of keystrokes that will get you into diagnostic mode,

Given that it is so new (and still under warranty), you want an exchange, not a repair.  This is way too new for you to be having this type of difficulty.

As to your question, "what will Apple do?"  They will look at it, press the power button, check your charger and then then they will give you another machine.  They won't attempt to repair it.

Comment: So the OP can kiss their data goodbye?

Answer (score 4):

There is one more thing you can try other than just mashing the power button.

You can try to reset the System Management Controller (SMC) by unplugging the power from the MacBook Pro, holding down the left hand control, shift and option keys and then holding down the power button for 10 seconds. Then plug the power back in and try turning it back on as normal.

Here is the thing that made a difference in my case: I'd have to wait approximately 3-4 hours with the computer unplugged for the battery to completely drain before it would work. (I worked this out after a trip to the Genius Bar.)

Answer (score 1):

MACBOOKS HAVE A SAFETY MECHANISM FOR HUMIDITY. Observe, if your macbook does not turn on on rainy days, especially when you live in tropics where humidity and condensation are extreme, do the following : remove screws and the back lid and dry the inside with hairdryer for about 1 minute. Also you can take your mackbook for a short while to an air conditioned room, which also makes it turn on. Google this topic, there are more reports and solutions available. Crazy, huh ? Of course you should not keep electronics in such humid conditions but realistically, how are you supposed to comply with that in some climates ? I was agonizing with this for about a year, I even almost resorted to buying a new macbook, before I came up with the idea to google something so insane... and it was the solution.